# no preceding characters in regexp statement

Tags: regex, oracle

So I have attempted to use a negative look back in a regexp statement and have looked online at other solutions but they don't seem to work for me so obviously I am doing something wrong-

I am looking for a return on the first line but the others should be null. Essentially I need CT CHEST or CT LUNG
Any assistance TIA

```
with test (id, description) as (
  select 1, 'CT CHEST HIGH RESOLUTION, NO CONTRAST'                         from dual union all --want this
  select 2, 'INJECTION, THORACIC TRANSFORAMEN EPIDURAL, NON NEUROLYTIC W IMAGE GUIDANCE.'                 from dual union all   --do not want this
  select 3, 'The cow came back. But the dog went for a walk'    from dual) --do not want this 
  select id, description, regexp_substr(description, '(?<![a-z]ct).{1,20}(CHEST|THOR|LUNG)',1,1,'i') from test;
```

Comment: FYI, oracle database does not support look behind or look ahead.

Comment: ah-well that's no fun!

Comment: Agreed, look ahead and look behind are nice tools in the regular expression tool box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Leverage Oracle Subexrpession Parameter to Check for `CT`**

I would leverage the use of subexpressions to use a pattern like this:

```
'regexp_substr(description, '(^| )((ct ).*((CHEST)|(THOR)|(LUNG)))', 1, 1,'i', 2)`
```

-subexpression 1 to look for beginning of line or a space: `(^| )`

-subexpression 3 to look for 'CT': `(ct )`

-allow for other characters: .*

-subexressions 5,6,7: `(CHEST)|(THOR)|(LUNG)`

-subexpression 2 which contain subexpression 3 an subexprssion 4

I use the last optional parameter to identify that I want subexpression 2.

```
    WITH test (id, description) as (
          SELECT 1
               , 'CT CHEST HIGH RESOLUTION , NO CONTRAST'
            FROM dual
           UNION ALL --want this
          SELECT 2
               , 'INJECTION , THORACIC TRANSFORAMEN EPIDURAL , NON NEUROLYTIC W IMAGE GUIDANCE.'
            FROM dual
           UNION ALL --do not want this
          SELECT 3
               , 'The cow came back. But the dog went FOR a walk'
    FROM dual
         ) --do not want this
  SELECT id
       , description
       , regexp_substr(description, '(^| )((ct ).*((CHEST)|(THOR)|(LUNG)))', 1, 1,'i', 2)
    FROM test;
```

Comment: That helped immensely-thanks. Definitely is much better at extracting the components.

Comment: oralce's implementation of regular expressions is not bad, but you have to work around the lack of look ahead and look behind features. using subexpressions is one approach people have taken to compensate for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_substr(description,'([^A-Z]|^)[CT].{1,20}(CHEST|THOR|LUNG)',1,1,'i')
```

works